# Best practices for validating emails in a text area

Tags: input-fields, email, validation, email-verification

I want to allow my users to add email recipients in a text area by just writing their addresses manually or copy & paste them from somewhere - email addresses are separated via a comma or new line.

**How do you validate an email address?**

[image: If it's an incorrect address, let's say, john.doe@example,com, how do you tell the user that it's incorrect?]

If it's an incorrect address, let's say, **john.doe@example,com**, how do you tell the user that it's incorrect?

**A)** **Show them a notification under the text area?**

If you've got multiple mistakes, you can always expand the notification underneath and make it scrollable.
[image]

**B)** **Offer a tooltip / notification?**

This is option would be very frustrating when the user has multiple mistakes.
[image]

**C)** **Do you offer any validation at all?**

AFAIK, email validation isn't 100% accurate whatever you do - you can never have all the edge cases thought through. So, you might end up creating a nuisance if you don't validate a legitimate email.

Comment: It's a good question but alas, it would only get you opinionated answers. Personally, I prefer a blend of A and C. Highlight blatant format errors, repetitions, etc. with a generic error message underneath and forget about checking the existence of an email id or the site extension

Comment: You should edit your question to be more about what is good or bad, UX wise about these options, rather than which one people would choose, because that encourages opinion-based answers.

Comment: Thanks for the info on this! Will edit the question ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made some valid points.

However, option C makes the most sense. Many organizations have a practice where bulk emails are sent, and it may inlvolve users copy pastying more than 100-200 email addresses in one go. In that case, option A is a big NO-NO. You don't want the user to individually search for the wrong addresses and sit and fix them.

Also, you're correct. Email validation cannot be 100% accurate, so all big email clients will let you enter any email address. However, I think you could combine option B and C. For example -

[image]

You could use colors to represent validation states. If 100% valid (if it satisfies all the pre-determined validation criterias) it can be a green pill, and if it doesn't satisfy all criterias, it can be an orange pill (to indicate that something **MAY** be wrong with that email address) with a question mark icon (or any icon/no icon) which can provide some useful information on mouse hover (tap on mobile). This should not, however, prevent the user from sending the email.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info!

I was also thinking about exploring coloured pills and adding a help icon in case we have trouble validating that email.

Completely agree that this should not prevent the user from sending the email. This should just be a visual notification that something is wrong / unsure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you find "best practice" by looking at what everyone else is doing. So look at how your email clients behave. Gmail doesn't seem to do any validation. And here's Outlook:

[image]